# how can i left truncate a string in c?

Tags: c, c-strings, trim

i get  a string of numbers for example: 1234567
i want to get leave  only the 4 digit from right to left. output example: 4567

I tried to use formatting the string, and i also used "atoi" to try to process it like a integer, but i didn't have success

this is one of my attempts:

```
int main()
{
    char val[20]="1234567";
    
    int num; 
    num = atoi(val);
    sprintf(val, "%-4d", num);
    printf("%s", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "leave" where? In the output? Copy to another string? Copy to the beginning of the original string?

Comment: `strlen()` gives you the length. `-4` gives you an offset. If that's >= 0, then perfect.

Comment: `atoi(val + strlen(val)-4)`

Comment: You can also use `num % 10000`.

Comment: @Barmar  - `atoi(val + strlen(val)-4)` -- only after you check that the strlen is  >= 4.  Doing that with "123" will go horribly wrong  :)

Comment: printf("%s\n", &val[strlen(val) - 4]);

Comment: @eduardo franco, With `char val[20]="-1234567";`, (a negative), what output is desired?

Comment: @eduardo franco, `char val[20]` large enough for a string for all 63-bit `int`.   Curious, why 20 and not 21 (to handle 64-bit `int`), not 12 (to handle 32-bit `int`), or much larger?

Comment: What type of result do you want? A number represented by the last four digits of the string? A copy of the last four digits in a new array, still as characters, not a number? A pointer to where the last four characters are in the original array? Output of the last four characters? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I don't think atoi works the way you intend it to

Edit: The previous answer did not work so try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void truncStr(char* str, int xlen) {
    int length = strlen(str);
    if (length > xlen) {
        memmove(str, str + (length - xlen), xlen + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "1234567";
    int xlen = 4;

    printf("Before truncation: %s\n", str);
    truncStr(str, xlen);
    printf("After truncation: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code produced in my computer the following output Before truncation: 1234567
After truncation: 1237.  Your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: It is a very incorrect behavior to copy and paste my code after I pointed to that your own original code has undefined behavior.  And I wonder who after that upvoted your answer, your friends?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with the string. Do it with the number after parsing.

```
int main()
{
    char val[20]="1233456";
    
    int num; 
    num = atoi(val);
    sprintf(val, "%-4d", num % 10000);
    printf("%s", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked, thank you!!, but could you tell me what "% 10000" does? please :)

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator. So it's the remainder when the number is divided by 10000, which is the last 4 digits.

Comment: @Barmar what about `char str[]="45363456864583769543874598453763459867459854768459745896745689456745986745";`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the character array that contains a string like that

```
char val[20]="1233456";
```

and want that the array would contain its last four (or other number) characters then just write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

size_t n = strlen( val );

if ( n > 4 ) memmove( val, val + n - 4, 5 );
```

Here us a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char val[20] = "1233456";

    size_t last_n = 4;

    size_t len = strlen( val );

    if (len > last_n) memmove( val, val + len - last_n, last_n + 1 );

    puts( val );
}
```

The program output is

```
3456
```

You can write a separate function that will do the task as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *last_n( char *s, size_t n )
{
    size_t len = strlen( s );

    if (len > n) memmove( s, s + len - n, n + 1 );

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    char val[20] = "1233456";

    puts( last_n( val, 4 ) );
}
```

Always try to write a more general code.

For example if the array contains a sequence of digits that can not be represented in a number of the type `int` then the approach with using the function `atoi` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
printf("%s", val + 3);
```

or a computed offset if you want the right-hand four digits.

```
int offset = (int)strlen(val) - 4;
if(offset < 0)
    offset = 0;
printf("%s", val + offset);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you're given a number as a string, I guess it'll a very big number.
You could just return another string that will contain only the last 4 digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char val[20]="1233456";
    int length = strlen(val);
    char output[5];
    int outputLength = 0;
    
    for(int i = length - 4; i < length; i++) {
        output[outputLength++] = val[i];
    }
    output[outputLength] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: I am sorry. I by mistake changed your answer instead of my own answer.:) I restored your answer.

Comment: Not my DV but `char output[4];` will overflow.

Comment: You're right.  I've modified the size. Thanks